# AWS Ami Linux supervisor failed

Tags: linux, php, amazon-web-services

I already deployed my laravel application on server AWS. But when I execute following command:

```
[root]# /usr/local/bin/supervisorctl restart laravelapp2
```

It gives me `laravelapp2:ERROR (no such process)` for the following command:

```
[root]# /usr/local/bin/supervisorctl restart laravelapp2:*
```

The application end as `abnormal termination`.

Running as follow gives me `command not found`

```
[root]# supervisord
```

Following is my `supervisord.conf` settings:

```
[program:laravelapp2]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/html/artisan queue:work sqs --sleep=3 --tries=3 --daemon
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=ec2-user
numprocs=8
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/html/worker.log
```

Comment: Try the absolute path to your PHP binary instead of `command=php /var...`

Comment: @HBruijn You mean absolute path to artisan?

Comment: Instead of php use `/usr/bin/php` in your configuration file supervisord.conf

Comment: @HBruijn nope it doest not work as well. Btw I am running the app on AWS AMI Linux container

Comment: From the `worker.log` this is the log `could not open input file: /var/www/html/artisan`

Comment: Typically such an error is either followed by a *"file not found'* (you made a typo or use a non-existent directory) or a *"permission denied"* (the permissions on the file or in the directory block your user) warning.

Comment: @HBruijn, it works now BUT. `/usr/local/bin/supervisorctl restart laravelapp:*` restart the app. The redis server fire an event `"GET" "laravel:illuminate:queue:restart` continuously and the value in redis server still not executed.